# Select Pandas Dataframe Column Value Based on Different Column Value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Pulling my hair our over this, though I'm sure someone will provide a simple answer.

```
data = [{'check': None, 'iterator': 1, 'x1': 1, 'x2': 2, 'x3':3},
         {'check': None,  'iterator': 2, 'x1': 1, 'x2': 2, 'x3':3},
         {'check': None,  'iterator': 3,  'x1': 1,  'x2': 2 , 'x3':3}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
display(df)
```

[image]

I'm trying to fill the check column by **shift**ing to the right by the value in the "iterator" column. I.e., the first row of "check" would be 1, the second would be 2, the third would be 3.

It's a simplification of a much larger dataset that I'm working on, so I'd appreciate vectorized code.

Comment: Any reason you can't just `df['check'] = df['iterator']`?

Comment: It would be great if you can also provide output dataframe here in the question too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to use `numpy`'s [advanced indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing):

```
df['check'] = df.filter(like="x").values[np.arange(len(df)), df.iterator - 1]
```

[image]

---

To avoid ambiguity, here is a different example:

```
data = [{'check': None, 'iterator': 2, 'x1': 3, 'x2': 4, 'x3':3},
        {'check': None,  'iterator': 1, 'x1': 1, 'x2': 5, 'x3':3},
        {'check': None,  'iterator': 2,  'x1': 2,  'x2': 2 , 'x3':1}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['check'] = df.filter(like="x").values[np.arange(len(df)), df.iterator-1]
df
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Thank you! Thank you!